# How can I put a text in a specific location on a plot

Tags: r, plot

I wrote this code in order to get the lines of the mean and the median on the frequency plot:

```
library(descr)
freq(loc_data$VAR1)
me<-mean(loc_data$VAR1)
med<-median(loc_data$VAR1)
abline(v=me,col='blue',lwd=2)
abline(v=med,col='red',lwd=2)
text(10, 15, "mean", col = "blue")
text(1, 15, "median", col = "red")
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the labels are located on the "0" line and I can't find a way to lift them to a higher location near the vertical lines. Any ideas?

Comment: Increase the `y` value in `text`. It corresponds to the values on the y-axis, i.e. you need values in the thousands.

Comment: take advantage of `?locator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following codes should do:

`text(10, 20000, "mean", col="blue")`
`text(1, 20000, "median", col="red")`

You have to pay attention to x and y-scales when you set coordinates for texts. There's an excellent ebook on R graphics called "R Fundamentals & Graphics".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above recommendation about taking your X and Y scales into account, you can also simply use the adj argument in text() to adjust the position of your text labels.

```
x<-rnorm(100)
hist(x)
x.mean<-mean(x)
x.median<-median(x)
abline(v=x.mean, col="red")
abline(v=x.median, col="blue")

text(x.mean,0,labels="mean", adj=c(2,-1), col="red")

text(x.median,0,labels="median", adj=c(-1,-1), col="blue")
```